# es6 access static method of child class from static method of parent?

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-class

I want to do this:

```
class Parent {
    static myMethod1(msg) {
    // myMethod2 is undefined
    this.constructor.myMethod2(msg);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  static myMethod2(msg) {
    console.log('static', msg);
  }
}

Child.myMethod1(1);
```

But it doesn't work.  Is this possible some other way?  I don't want to hard code Child.myMethod2 in Parent which I know would work since I want random child classes to be able to define/override the static method but call that method from the parent without prior knowledge of which class is the child.

Comment: Hi, this seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve so we can help you improve your architecture? In order to get your setup working.

Comment: @MaartenBicknese Are you saying this is an anti-pattern or that it is impossible?

Comment: I'm saying it is an anti-pattern, I'd be happy to help you find a good pattern to solve your issue.

Comment: @MaartenBicknese I got an answer below but I'm genuinely curious about why generically overriding static methods in a child that are referenced from a parent is an anti pattern.   Is there a blog post or article that covers this you can reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myMethod2` is undefined because the code is wrong. `this` is class constructor in static methods, and `this.constructor` is the constructor of a constructor, i.e. `Function`. It should be:

```
class Parent {
  static myMethod1(msg) {
    this.myMethod2(msg);
  }
}
```

This is antipattern, because `Parent` doesn't have `myMethod2`, and `Parent.myMethod1()` will result in error. It should either contain no-op `myMethod2`, or be labeled as abstract class to never be accessed directly.